# Entity Framework Issue, Inserting into many different Tables

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, insert

Hi I need to insert Purchase Order Header, and Details. Now Inserting data into PurchaseOrder Table was succesful but when I tried Inserting data into PurchaseOrderDetails it inserted data  into many different tables. I tried debugging it but I didn't find the problem. Also I checked SQL Profiler I found out that EF is inserting data to the ff tables"
NewProposal,Institution,Product,etc.

Please help me, how can I prevent EF from inserting data into other tables, I just need EF to insert data into PO and POdetails table.

Here's my Purchase Order Model:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int PurchaseOrderID {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string PurchaseOrderNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime PurchaseOrderDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    public bool isDraft { get; set; }

    public int? InstitutionID { get; set; }

    public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ReceivedDate { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public List<PODetail> PODetail { get; set; }

}
```

Here's the Purchase Order Details Model:

```
public class PODetail
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }


    public virtual PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual ULIV.ViewModels.NewProposal Proposal { get; set; }


    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    public bool isDraft { get; set; }

}
```

for your reference also, this is the NewProposal VM:

```
public class NewProposal
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Proposal ID")]
    public int ProposalID { get; set; }

    public int InstitutionID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("InstitutionID")]
    public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }

    public string ProposalCode { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Proposed Unit Price")]
    ///[Required]
    public decimal ProposedUnitPrice { get; set; }

    ///[Required]
    [Display(Name = "Proposed Volume")]
    public string ProposedVolume { get; set; }

    public string Remarks { get; set; }

    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    public int VaccineTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual VaccineType VaccineType { get; set; }


    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductModel Product {get; set;}


    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }


    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public decimal FinalUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal FinalVolume { get; set; }

    public decimal FinalTotalAmount { get; set; }

    public string RelatedProposalCode { get; set; }

    //public List<PODetail> PODetail { get; set; }

    public string getdatestring
    {
        get {
            return DateModified.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }

    public bool isDraft { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string DateDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly this is Create Action for saving the Purchase Orders:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PurchaseOrderViewModel purchaseorderviewmodel)
    {

        Session["PurchaseOrderNo"] = purchaseorderviewmodel.PurchaseOrderNo;

        purchaseorderviewmodel.AddedProposal  = (List<ULIV.ViewModels.NewProposal>)Session["AddedProposal"];


        int instituionId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["InstitutionID"]);          

        purchaseorderviewmodel.isDraft = true;

        purchaseorderviewmodel.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;

        purchaseorderviewmodel.DateModified = DateTime.Now;


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            try
            {
                ULIV.Models.PurchaseOrder newPO = new PurchaseOrder();
                newPO.Institution = db.Institutions.Find(instituionId);
                newPO.PurchaseOrderNo = purchaseorderviewmodel.PurchaseOrderNo;
                newPO.PurchaseOrderDate = purchaseorderviewmodel.PurchaseOrderDate;
                newPO.ReceivedDate = purchaseorderviewmodel.ReceivedDate;
                newPO.Remarks = purchaseorderviewmodel.Remarks;
                //newPO.Institution = 
                newPO.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                newPO.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
                newPO.isDraft = true;
                db.PurchaseOrders.Add(newPO);
                db.SaveChanges();

                var query = (from m in db.PurchaseOrders orderby m.PurchaseOrderID descending select m).Take(1).ToList();


                foreach (var d in purchaseorderviewmodel.AddedProposal)
                {
                    PODetail newPODetail = new PODetail();


                    foreach (var i in query)
                    {
                        newPODetail.PurchaseOrder = i;

                    }


                    newPODetail.Proposal = d;
                    newPODetail.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                    newPODetail.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
                    newPODetail.isDraft = true;

                    db.PODetails.Add(newPODetail);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }


            Session["AddedProposal"] = null;


            return RedirectToAction("Index","Fulfillment");
        }


        ViewBag.Proposal = new SelectList(db.NewProposal.Where(x => x.Status.StatusID == 3), "ProposalID", "ProposalCode");
        return View(purchaseorderviewmodel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
newPODetail.Proposal = d;
```

with `d` being part of your `ViewModel`. This means that you are setting as Proposal an instance that doesn't come from your `DbContext`. Because of that, EF thinks is a new thing (because it doesn't know it) and does an insert.

What you can do is tu find the actual `Proposal` from the `DbContext` using `db.Proposals.Find(d.Id)` or something like that or to use `db.Attach(d)` to attach the object to the current `DbContext`.

More information regarding attach: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach%28v=vs.103%29.aspx